# what type of functions has $f(x+y) \geq f(x) + f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I was working on some $L^p$ inequalities and stumbled up on this. 
I know that 
$$f(x+y) \geq f(x) + f(y)$$ if $f$ is convex and monotone increasing. Does this hold for "only if"? And is there a name for this type of functions, like "convex" and "monotone"?

Thanks!

Comment: For the first question: no. [There are real functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation#Proof_of_the_existence_of_other_solutions) $f$ satisfying $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ with dense graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name you are looking for is [superadditive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superadditivity).

Even for nice continuous functions, superadditivity does not imply convexity. Indeed, rewriting the inequality as 
$$\frac{f(x+y)}{x+y}\ge \frac{x}{x+y} \frac{f(x)}{x}+ \frac{y}{x+y} \frac{f(y)}{y}$$
we see that it holds whenever  $f(x)/x$ is increasing.

As an example, I took $f(x)=x\min(x,1)$; this function is superadditive by the above, but it's not convex:

[image: not convex]

Answer (score 3):

Even it need not be continuous: The greatest integer function $f(x) =[x]$ satisfies superadditivity!